# node-red parse html table from specific tr:nth-child location not working with cheerio

Tags: jquery, html, css, node-red, cheerio

Hi I have created a flow in node-red to parse a table (#weather_table) from this address https://www.vcwatershed.net/fws/reservoir.html and I am unable to extract all data at row 3 of the table "#weather_table". refer below showing the tr:child info i am after

```
<html>
 <head>...</head>
  <body>
   <body">
       <a name="top"></a>
       <h1>VCWPD Area Reservoir Report</h1>
       <table border="1" id="weather_table">
         <tbody>
           <tr class="header">...</tr>
           <tr class="row0">...</tr>
           <tr class="row1">
             <td>691</td>
             <td>Lake Casitas Dam level</td>
             <td>11/29/2019 09:29</td>
             <td align="Right">567.00</td>
             <td align="Right">238,000</td>
             <td align="Right">500.34</td>
             <td align="Right">98,037</td>
             <td align="Right">---</td>
             <td align="Right">0</td>
             <td align="Right">-66.66</td>
             <td align="Right">41.2%</td>
            </tr>
           <tr class="row0">...</tr>
           <tr class="row1">...</tr>
           <tr class="row0">...</tr>
           <tr class="row1">...</tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </body">
  </body>
</html>
```

I have used the html node and cheerio node using selectors such as:
`#weather_table`
and something really specific
`#weather_table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(1)`

When I use the Selector as #weather_table the msg.payload shows only the headers of the #weather_table.
I have even tried the "*" symbol. This does not bring back the table information but the source code which indicates there is json file used as a reference. Would this have anything to do with my inability to parse the row information from the table? The json file name is `json/reservoir.json`

I have used the "cheerio node" with the following:

```
msg.payload=$('#weather_table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3)').text();
return msg;
```

and alternatively the "html node" with

```
#weather_table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3)
```

Which doesn't show any of the table content in msg.payload even if its just

```
#weather_table > tbody
```

I am stumped at this point

I was expecting to return the third row of the table "#weather_table" to populate a table with the table headers on my node-red dashboard but all I can obtain is the headings. 
At this point I was thinking it probably requires some J query? But I am out of my depth there and would need some help.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: Trying to get the data on the third row of the table "#weather_table" (Site 691, Lake Casitas Dam Level ) [link](https://www.vcwatershed.net/fws/reservoir.html)

Comment: As a string? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: As a string is fine. It is the data fields along that row I am after i.e. the td values

Comment: added html for clarity

Comment: It's helpful when you can identify exactly what you want. For example: 'I would like to get the string "Lake Casitas Dam level"'

Comment: Website appears down,, but it's possible that the data is injected via JS.